# App hangs when using realm and viewPager

Tags: android, realm

Well, I'm using Realm to save data and its working perfectly. But when i use it in one of the fragments to save data, other fragments start to hang and then app shuts down. I'm using retrofit to get data. I'm not posting all classes, only those methods which are relevant.

1) I check if internet connection is available. If not i get data from realm and place it in recycler view:

```
public void internet() {
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getActivity());
    // Check if Internet present
    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
    if (isInternetPresent == false) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Internet Not Present", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new AdapterClass(this, realm.where(AndroidVersion.class).findAllAsync()));

    } else {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                RealmResults<AndroidVersion> realmList = realm.where(AndroidVersion.class).findAll();
                realmList.deleteAllFromRealm();
            }
        });
        loadJSON();
    }
}
```

2) If connection is available i call loadJSON method and get data, set it with recycler view and also save it in realm:

```
public void loadJSON() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://54.187.18.119/lived2d/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
    Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
            JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
            data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getExplore()));
            adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(data);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                final int finalI = i;
                realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        AndroidVersion androidVersion = new AndroidVersion();
                        androidVersion.setName(data.get(finalI).getName());
                        androidVersion.setLname(data.get(finalI).getLname());
                        androidVersion.setTitle(data.get(finalI).getTitle());
                        androidVersion.setLocation(data.get(finalI).getLocation());
                        androidVersion.setTotal_comment(data.get(finalI).getTotal_comment());
                        androidVersion.setTotal_like(data.get(finalI).getTotal_like());
                        androidVersion.setDate(data.get(finalI).getDate());
                        androidVersion.setId(data.get(finalI).getId());
                        androidVersion.setUser_id(data.get(finalI).getUser_id());
                        realm.copyToRealm(androidVersion);

                        RealmResults<AndroidVersion> results = realm.where(AndroidVersion.class).findAll();
                        Log.d("ALL ANSWER", String.valueOf(results));
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            //Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
            if (t.getMessage().equals("timeout")) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                        .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launche)
                        .setTitle("Network Error")
                        .setMessage("Connection is weak or not available. Please try again after some time.")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            }

                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

RecyclerAdapter class:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android;
public static final String KEY_USERID = "userid";
public static final String KEY_EXPLOREID = "exploreid";

public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android) {
    this.android = android;
    if (ExploreFragment.srl.isRefreshing()) {
        ExploreFragment.srl.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_explore_fragment, parent, false);
    return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Context context = holder.imageView.getContext();
    String st = android.get(position).getImage();
    String image = st.replace("\\", "");
    int length = android.get(position).getTitle().length();
    if (length >= 60) {
        String title = android.get(position).getTitle().substring(0, 60) + "...";
        holder.tv1.setText(title);
    } else {
        holder.tv1.setText(android.get(position).getTitle());
    }
    holder.time.setText(android.get(position).getDate());
    holder.totallikes.setText(android.get(position).getTotal_like());
    holder.location.setText(android.get(position).getLocation());
    holder.name.setText(android.get(position).getName());
    holder.comment.setText(android.get(position).getTotal_comment());
    holder.lname.setText(android.get(position).getLname());
    if (image.equals("")) {

        Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.profilepi).into(holder.imageView);
    } else {

        Picasso.with(context).load("http://ec2-54-187-18-119.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/lived2d/" + image).resize(100, 100).centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);
    }

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return android.size();
}
```

AdapterClass class:

```
public class AdapterClass extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterClass.RecyclerViewHolder> {
private RealmResults<AndroidVersion> arrayLists;
private Realm realm;

public AdapterClass(ExploreFragment second, RealmResults<AndroidVersion> allAsync) {
    this.arrayLists = allAsync;
}

public AdapterClass(ArrayList<AndroidVersion> data) {
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_explore_fragment, parent, false);
    return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    AndroidVersion user = arrayLists.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(user.getName());
    holder.lname.setText(user.getLname());
    holder.location.setText(user.getLocation());
    holder.tv1.setText(user.getTitle());
    holder.time.setText(user.getDate());
    holder.totallikes.setText(user.getTotal_like());
    holder.lname.setText(user.getLname());
    holder.comment.setText(user.getTotal_comment());
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayLists.size();
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did u see anything wrong in logs..? Can u post logcat of app when the app hangs..?

Comment: I/Choreographer: Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.252ms
I/Choreographer: Skipped 109 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: The application is not crashing, it just shuts down automatically.

Comment: `realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();` move this out of loop. Only call it once

Comment: removed it from for loop, but didn't worked. Should i remove it from onBindViewHolder too, as its also a loop?

Comment: @BhaveshMisri I think u could do that intialization in constructor.? Try that once..

Comment: No, still not working. The fragment in which I'm fetching data from realm itself works fine, i.e  its working(scrolling) smoothly. But when i go on some other fragment and scroll down, the app shuts down. If internet connection is available, apps work just fine. All the fragments work properly. I'm not able to understand where the problem is? I know its in AdapterClass where I'm binding data from realm to recycler view, but i don't know why.

Comment: Can you try to profiling it to see what function takes lots of time? and BTW, Realm instance which is returned by `getDefaultInstance()` needs to be closed by calling `Realm.close()`. Otherwise leak might happen.

Comment: called Realm.close(), still didn't work. I'm trying to figure out why application is doing too much work on main thread :')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now. It was because i was using page transform animation, which was causing lot of work on main thread. I removed the animation and now its working properly.